# how can i use regex to match this string in android?

Tags: android, regex, image

I want to grab img tag from text returned from json data like that

```
‫#رصد| #انقلاب_3يوليو| اليوم ... مبني المركبات العسكري في صلاح سالم<br /> <br /> تصوير المواطن الصحفي :  عبدالرحمن النحاس‬<br/><br/><a href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=598075296936250&amp;set=a.280183138725469.58204.103622369714881&amp;type=1&amp;relevant_count=1" id="" title="" target="" onclick="" style=""><img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1239478_598075296936250_1910331324_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

i want to grab this

```
<img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1239478_598075296936250_1910331324_s.jpg" alt="" />
```

what the reqular expression i must use in android to match it

I used this code but it is not working

```
String content = e.getString("content");
                    String img = "";
                    Pattern p = Pattern
                            .compile("<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(content);

                    if (m.matches()) {
                        Log.d("true", m.group(0).toString());
                        img = m.group(0).toString();
                    }
                    Log.d("image", "image : " + content);
```

Comment: use jsoup to extract data from html tags

Comment: hmmm .. i prefer regex because i will treat with string .. not url

Comment: Bad idea, think again.

Comment: `I want to grab img tag from text returned from json data like that` Dunno his code make sense for a regex he's not getting the string from pure html correct?

Comment: i grab it from here https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=103622369714881&format=json -- after parsing json data in content .. i grab img tags

Comment: and why regex is bad idea ??

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions to parse HTML is a [very bad idea](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Better to use a true HTML parser and walk the DOM tree to get what you want.

You also need to be careful about proper encoding, since you want Arabic text.

Comment: ok, like what .. i want grab img tag from string return from database not html page

Comment: Why on earth do you have an image tag in a database?  Why should a database care about markup?

Comment: because it is returned from json data like string contains img tags

Comment: please i just want regex for that .. i need it

Answer (score 1):

Well... you know you can get the JSON object and parse that without regex? that is probably the best approach. Then you can just strip out the content without worrying about parsing anything from a string because it automatically puts it into variables for you.

[How to parse JSON](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/)

It can become very messy to mess around with regex for the reasons @duffymo posted above me.

edit:

I see what you are trying to do.... parse the image out of the content section correct? There needs to be two things involved here yes.. regular expressions and also json parsing. You need to grab all the content fields from the json parser then use regex on those to extract the images. That's what you are trying to do correct?